# Sqoop - Manipulate a Mysql table before importing to HDFS

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

Can we edit the table by selecting specific columns or other conditions in MYSQL to save as a new table in the MYSQL database before import to HDFS?

Comment: To answer the original title. You don't **need** Sqoop. Several other tools can be used. For example, Spark

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we could save a new table to MySQL before exporting it to HDFS. Also we could edit the file with vi editor and export it to HDFS. But it would be much easier to use sqoop.

Comment: Edit what file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqoop evel before sqoop import for some purpose.